# Popups being blocked on our app but not others

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I am noticing that my share popups are being blocked on our application but not others.

Here is the code execution:

1.) User enters web page.

2.) User clicks on facebook or twitter or googleplus share icon

3.) Onclick event passes the request to an internal controller that saves some information and then redirects back to the originating webpage. This time, however, there is a request parameter that invokes the usage of opening a new window.

The code I have that invokes opening a new window is (for this example we will use facebook):

```
var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+copyLink;
window.open(url,'newwindow','width=600,height=600');
```

Now, if i enable popups it works fine. The problem is the user has to enable popups every time.

Is it a server issue? What is the reason why on other apps they don't have blocked popups but for **OUR APP we cannot use popups without enabling popups**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say "the user" are you talking about one guy? There must be some difference in configuration if you are seeing one behavior and someone else is seeing another. Different browser? Different extensions? In any case, the solution is to experiment until you find a mostly reliable way of executing the popup.

Comment: @Jeff-InventorChromeOS Well I just went to nytimes.com for the first time and clicked on share dialog and there were no popup blocking occurring. Same browser, same computer.

Comment: you can only open a popup from a click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, your application attempts to open a popup window following a page load.  The nytimes.com popup appeared in response to a mouse click.

There is an important difference between these two ways to open a popup: the latter follows a user-initiated action but the former does not.  As a result, popup blockers will generally block the former but not the latter.  A lot of users wouldn't be too surprised if a popup opened when they clicked a button, but they would be more irritated if a popup appeared when a page loaded.  The fact that your popup was ultimately triggered by an action on another page doesn't matter - what happens if you manually add to the URL the extra parameter that opens the popup?

[Here's an old page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537632(v=vs.85).aspx) on popup blockers.  It may describe the popup blocker in IE6 (of all browsers), but I think it still provides a reasonable explanation of when popup blockers typically permit or block popups.

Would it be possible to open a popup for your share dialog before calling back to the server?  I would expect that opening a popup in the onclick handler would work without needing to explicitly allow popups.